# How to position menu correctly?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this [menu](http://event.xnicram.pl/) (only background on the left on menu should't be visible) also have article template [here](http://event.xnicram.pl/index3.html)
I try to join it together [here](http://event.xnicram.pl/index2.html) but if menu have correct position then article is always below menu and if article have correct position then menu is below. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to how I understood your question you want to remove the left gap of the menu and have it in the same position in the article.

To achieve this simply add the following styles to your menu div.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
//if you want your menu always on the left side 
#menu{ //your menu
position:fixed; //added
width:300px; //
min-width:300px; // yours,even thought you don't need this
left:0;
top:0;
height:100%;

}

#other_content{ //right to your menu
margin-left:300px;
//and other styles you do
}
```

HTML (this is how i imagined you want your page after i looked at it):

```
<body>
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="other_content"></div>
</body>
```

And if you want more help, please post some code, so we can have a deeper look at what you want